# bitxor operation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to understand why the original image is not coming with this code. The resulting image `receive` is yellowish in color, instead of being similar to the image `Img_new`.

```
Img=imread(‘lena_color.tif’);
Img_new=rgb2gray(img);
Send=zeroes(size(Img_new);
Receive= zeroes(size(Img_new);
Mask= rand(size(Img_new);
for i=1 :256
    for j=1:256
        Send(i,j)=xor( Img_new(i,j),mask(i,j));
    End
End

image(send);
imshow(send);

for i=1 :256
    for j=1:256
        receive(i,j)=xor( send(i,j),mask(i,j));
    End
End

image(receive);
imshow(receive);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Firstly your code is *full* of syntactical errors (MATLAB is case sensitive so `end` and `End` are not the same and the same goes for `Same` and `Receive`)

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems in your code.

1. MATLAB is case sensitive so `end` and `End` is not the same. Same goes for `receive`, and `send`.
2. MATLAB has a lot of matrix-based operations so *please* use for loops as a last resort since most of these operations can be executed by MATLAB's optimized routines for matrices.
3. MATLAB's [`xor`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xor.html) returns the logical [`xor`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xor.html) so when it sees two values (or matrices of values) it  doesn't matter if it's `234 xor 123` or `12 xor 23` since it is equivalent to `1 xor 1` and `1 xor 1`. **You're looking for** [`bitxor`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/bitxor.html) which does the bitwise `xor` on each element of the matrix and I've used it in my code below. This is the only way you can retrieve the information with the `pixel == xor(xor(pixel,key),key)` operation (assuming that's what you want to do).
4. [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html) returns a real value from `0 - 1` ; therefore, to do a successful bitwise `xor`, you need numbers from `0 - 255`. Hence, in my code, you'll see that `mask` has random values from `0-255`.

**Note:** I've used `peppers.png` since it's available in MATLAB. Replace it with `lena_color.tif`.

```
%%# Load and convert the image to gray
img = imread('peppers.png');
img_new = rgb2gray(img);

%%# Get the mask matrix
mask = uint8(rand(size(img_new))*256);

%%# Get the send and receive matrix
send   = bitxor(img_new,mask);
receive = bitxor(send,mask);

%%# Check and display
figure;imshow(send,[0 255]);
figure;imshow(receive,[0 255]);
```

#### Update:

```
%%# Get mask and img somehow (imread, etc.)
img = double(img);
mask_rgb = double(repmat(mask,[1 1 3]));
bitxor(img,mask);
```

If instead, you choose to make everything `uint8` instead of double, then I urge you to check if you are losing data anywhere. `img` is `uint8` so there is no loss, but if any of the values of `mask` is greater than `255` then making it `double` will lead to a loss in data.

Comment: Thanx..this is what i wanted.i figured it out.

Comment: @gavishna, if you're happy with this answer, it would be good if you would accept it.

Comment: One small suggestion... you can use [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html) to generate the mask like so: `mask = randi([0 255],size(img_new),'uint8');`

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks! I should probably use it more often.

Comment: There is another problem i am facing due to bitxor.The code is as under
img=imread('lena_color.tif'); 
rawData=dlmread('mask.txt'); mask=reshape(rawData(1:262144),512,512); % Till now its ok send=bitxor(img,mask); %This gives error of Error using ==> bitxor Inputs must be unsigned integers of the same class or scalar doubles. 
figure,subplot(1,2,1); imshow(send,[0 255]); receive=bitxor(send,mask); imshow(receive,[0 255]);

Comment: i did double(img);double(mask); but error did not go 2. the same code works for random nos generated using rand and converted into uint8. So i tried to convert mask into uint8(mask(size(img)*256); But to no avail.problem still persists. 3. size(img) = 512 512 3 size(mask)= 512 512 mask(size(img));= 34 34 9 is it not necessary for mask array to be 512 512 3 dimension? Also how to mitigate this error?thanx a ton in advance

Comment: Before you execute `send = bitxor(img,mask)`, type `whos img mask`. This will tell you the dimensions and the class of these variables. They should be the same. Also, if it's class `double`, that's OK, **if** it only has integers (which is the right thing since you're dealing with images).

Comment: @Jacob. Mask has only integers.whos img  gives img 512x512x3  bytes=786432 clas uint8 array
whos mask gives 512x512  Bytes 2097152 double array.
Now what to do.Kindly help.

Comment: So you want to use the same mask for all 3 components of the image?

Comment: Also, the `mask` and `img` have to be the same type. So if you want both to be double, and assuming you want to use the same mask for the 3 components of `img`, we copy the mask along the third dimension. I've updated this in the answer.

Comment: Thank u Jacob very much.It worked.The conversion of both img and mask to double data type works but converting to uint8 yield an error that it must be scalar or double.Anyways,thanx a ton for your patience and time.